# Is it more resource efficient to have to Pods, or two containers in one Pod?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod

I have test environment where HA is not important but rather resources efficiency, so would you recommend in that regard to create one Pod with multiple containers where it make sense of course, where containers are tight coupled or to have one Pod for every service? Does this have any impact on resources at all?

I will give an example if for instance I have php application, and then nginx proxy and then filebeat service that is listening logs, what would be better to have 3 pods for this 3 things or one pod with 3 containers. And when I say better I mean to use less memory, cpu, etc.

Comment: What kind of resources?

Comment: @zerkms CPU, memory, etc...

Comment: A particular containers' CPU and memory consumption does not change on whether it runs in one pod or split.

Comment: @zerkms what about during deployment and update?

Comment: If you want to be resource efficient, look at scale to zero implementations (GraalVM). Id assume putting two containers per pod is more efficient (marginally?) but would be harder to manage as you're pods are going to be more tightly coupled together - If/when you need to scale one but not the other container, you no longer have the choice without considerable effort and it becomes less resource efficient. You may only need 1 nginx proxy server for the next 5-10 years, but possibly 2-10 php app servers, say.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between both solutions should not be significant (negligible ?).
However, depending on your approach, the management effort might be quite significantly different.

With one component in a dedicated pod you need to somehow synchronise live cycle of all pods (php +  nginx + filebeat) whenever you spin just one, new application up.

With all of them in one pod you just need to create/delete **one** pod.